# Сказуемое (именное?)

Tags: синтаксис

Какое сказуемое в предложении *Был хороший, теплый и тихий день*?

Почему мне так хочется назвать прилагательные определениями, а не однородными частями составного именного сказуемого?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Какое сказуемое в предложении ***Был хороший, теплый и тихий день***?

Сказуемое здесь  —  бытийный глагол **был**;

подлежащее  —  **день**;

**хороший**, **теплый** и **тихий**  —  определения.

Ср.:

***День был хороший, теплый и тихий.***

Здесь **был**  —  связка;

сказуемое (составное именное)  —  **был хороший, теплый и тихий**;

**день**  —  подлежащее.